# How to attach file in contact us mail

Tags: magento2, email-templates, contact-us, contact-form, attachment

I have a contact form with a field to attach the file but I don't the way how to attach that uploaded file to the email template of contact us mail in Magento
[image: This is the contact form image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Created extension which does this

https://github.com/DominicWatts/ContactAttachment